# java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getMaximumWindowBounds() does not change after screen mode changes

Tags: java, awt

I've noticed that if the screen mode is changed outside of Java that `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getMaximumWindowBounds()` still returns the size before the screen size changed.
But `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode()` works and shows the new resolution.

I've traced `getMaximumBounds()` to a call to `GraphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration()` that I suspect is using a stale configuration.

My question is: is there some way to tell Java the screen configuration has changed or is this just a bug?

Thanks.

Here is a simple app that shows the bug:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class test {
  public static void print() {
    try {
      Rectangle r = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
      System.out.println("max window bounds=" + r);
      DisplayMode mode = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
      System.out.println("mode=" + mode.getWidth() + "x" + mode.getHeight());
      GraphicsConfiguration gc = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
      Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
      System.out.println("insets=" + insets);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      print();
      System.out.println("Change video mode and press Enter to continue...");
      System.in.read();
      print();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me on a Win7 box (JDK 1.7.0_21 and 1.6.0_16): "max window bounds" is updated as expected. Do you have the same issue with other JDK/JRE or on other OSes?

Comment: I'm running this on Linux (Fedora 20) JRE 7 update 51.  Must be a bug related to Linux.

Comment: Also works with JRE 1.7.0_51 on Windows... Why don't you use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode()` to get your bounds? multiple-screens configuration?

Comment: getMaximumWindowBounds() accounts for areas cut out for taskbar, etc.  But I can call java.awt.Toolkit.getScreenInsets() to get this size and subtract it from the DisplayMode size.  That is what I'll do.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that works for me:

```
  public static Rectangle getMaximumBounds() {
    Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration());
    DisplayMode mode = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode();
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.x = insets.left;
    bounds.y = insets.top;
    bounds.width = mode.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
    bounds.height = mode.getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    return bounds;
  }
```

But I've noticed other awt function don't adjust due to the screen mode change.  JPopupMenu.show() places menus way off.  Pffff....oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Based on Peter Quiring's answer, I added support for multiple monitors, based on where the component is located.

```
 public static Rectangle getMaximumBounds(Component comp) {
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = comp.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
    DisplayMode mode = gc.getDevice().getDisplayMode();
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;
    for(GraphicsDevice device : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
        Rectangle deviceBounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        if(deviceBounds.contains(gc.getBounds())) {
            xPos = gc.getBounds().x;
            yPos = gc.getBounds().y;
        }
    }
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    bounds.x = insets.left + xPos;
    bounds.y = insets.top + yPos;
    bounds.width = mode.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
    bounds.height = mode.getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    return bounds;
}
```